# how can I rebase a range of changes into another branch with just one commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have the branches like below:

```
             L--M   <-- master
            /
...--A--B--C
            \
             D--E--F--G--H-I--J--K   <-- dev(HEAD)
```

What I want to do is to copy the EFGHIJ to master with one commit, like below:

```
             L--M--N   <-- master
            /
...--A--B--C
            \
             D--E--F--G--H-I--J--K   <-- dev(HEAD)
```

The **N** should contain EFGHIJ changes.

I can use the rebase --onto command to rebase the changes to master

```
git rebase --onto master E~1 J
```

If I use git push, there would exist the *EFGHIJ* changes in master.
Maybe I need use *git rebase -i* command to change them into one, but, the question is, I cannot see the change history the previous changes applied by git rebase --onto!

How can I commit them with just one commit?

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but had the information I needed. Thanks for a well thought-out question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `git rebase --onto master E~1 J` run

```
git reset --soft M
git commit -m 'changes from E F G H I and J'
```

Done!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with a single command (`rebase -i`), but it requires manual intervention: you need to edit the todo list of the rebase:

```
git rebase -i --onto M E^ J
# then in vim: :2,$s/^pick/fixup/
# save and close vim, voilà
```

If you require a specific/different commit message, change `pick` in the first line to `reword` and enter your message accordingly.

---

Where does your requirement for a single command come from? Let me think a bit more, it might be possible with a combination of diff+apply (but then again, you have a pipe and it is actually two commands)

EDIT: diff+apply works, but you then need another command (commit), so I think going with rebase is the simplest and safest option. For completeness sake:

```
git checkout M
git diff E^ J | git apply
git commit -m 'Combination of commits E^..J'
```

Comment: The diff|apply does directly what the rebase does a lot of intermediate steps (which are then thrown away) to achieve.